# 301 редирект с регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, url, redirect

Год назад начал разработку сайта, при этом выбрал технологию построения url страниц таким образом, что к каждому компоненту адреса добавляется id из БД. Например,

```
mysite/news-2/some-news-12
mysite/articles-3/some-article-25
```

По такой же технологии реализован и роутер движка.

Однако сейчас я понял, что сильно ошибся в выборе технологии (так как такой вариант предпочтителен исключительно для веб-ресурсов, содержащих неограниченное количество обновляемых разделов/страниц). 
Теперь я хочу перейти к нормальному отображению url:
было `mysite/news-2/some-news-12`

станет `mysite/news/some-news`

Переписать роутер не проблема, но за год страницы хорошо проиндексировались, и я вынужден дополнительно реализовать грамотную переадресацию со старых адресов на новые. В данном случае необходимо использовать регулярные выражения, поэтому принято решение использовать php.

Реализацию вижу в таком вид (прописывается в начале роутера):

```
if ( проверить регуляркой СТАРЫЙ_АДРЕС ){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: НОВЫЙ_АДРЕС"); 
    exit(); 
}
```

также встречал и такую инструкцию:

```
…..
   header("Location: НОВЫЙ_АДРЕС",TRUE,301);
…..
```

Подскажите наиболее приемлемое решение для моего случая (а также по возможности само регулярное выражение – как найти и удалить выражения «-число» в конце компонентов url адреса)

Comment: если задача выглядит как только удаление цифр, то решайте ее на уровне сервера, а не пхп. Тот же редирект сделаете с помощью `RewriteRule` в `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Всё отлично работает, огромное спасибо  @teran за наводку на .htaccess. Итак, достаточно одной строки в .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)(\-\d+)$ //mysite.ru/$1
```